# set default xml namespace for openxml

Tags: xml, t-sql, xml-namespaces

this is probably a simple question, sorry.

I have an XMl file that starts out with these lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<MyData xmlns="http://xyz.com.au/schema/v1_10/MyData">
  <data>
    <patient>
      <link_id>{764C733A-64DE-4663-82B1-1A23B95FDFE2}</link_id>
```

I load it into an XML data type in a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE MMD (
Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
XMLData XML,
LoadedDateTime DATETIME)

INSERT INTO MMD (XMLData, LoadedDateTime)
SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn, GETDATE() 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Test.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;
```

I then query it like this:

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM MMD

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML

;with xmlnamespaces (default 'http://xyz.com.au/schema/v1_10/MyData/')
SELECT  distinct(link_id)
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'MyData/data/patient')
WITH 
(link_id [varchar](50) 'link_id') t

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
GO
```

The query returns 0 rows. But, if I remove the namespace from the second line of the file like this: from:

```
<MyData xmlns="http://xyz.com.au/schema/v1_10/MyData">
```

to:

```
<MyData>
```

then I get the results I expect!

I've read all the posts and tried all sorts of syntax variations without success.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Brian

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if `OPENXML` and `with xmlnamespaces` are meant to work together. It all works fine if I switch entirely to using [`xml` data type methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx) (and expand the sample to be valid xml):

```
declare @t table (XMLData xml)
insert into @t(XmlData) values ('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<MyData xmlns="http://xyz.com.au/schema/v1_10/MyData">
  <data>
    <patient>
      <link_id>{764C733A-64DE-4663-82B1-1A23B95FDFE2}</link_id>
    </patient>
  </data>
</MyData>')

;with xmlnamespaces (default 'http://xyz.com.au/schema/v1_10/MyData')
select distinct XmlData.value('(MyData/data/patient/link_id)[1]','varchar(50)')
from @t
```

Result:

```
--------------------------------------------------
{764C733A-64DE-4663-82B1-1A23B95FDFE2}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but I am struggling with that syntax. My background is not with MS T-SQL. I may need to go hit the books.